# Rails 3.2 - How to turn this complex query to be in parameterized format?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, prepared-statement

I am currently helping out a Rails 3.2 project.

Got this complex query that I would like to be in parameterized format.

> project.supporters.connection.select_all(
>  "SELECT t2.* FROM 
>   (SELECT MAX(id) AS max_supporter_id FROM supporters
>   WHERE
>   supporters.project_id = ?
>   GROUP BY supporters.supporter_id) AS
>   t1
>   INNER JOIN supporters AS t2
>   ON t1.max_supporter_id =
>   t2.id", 1).

Above query is what I would like to be like but I know it doesn't work because `select_all` doesn't do parameterized query.

So far this is what I got:

> project.supporters.group(:supporter_id).maximum(:id)
>  which will
>   generate this sql:
>  SELECT MAX("supporters"."id") AS maximum_id,
>   supporter_id AS supporter_id FROM "supporters" WHERE
>   "supporters"."project_id" = 1 GROUP BY supporter_id

But I haven't made significant progress to do the inner join and finally have the outer `SELECT`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project_id = 1
supporters = Arel::Table.new(:supporters)
max_id = supporters.project(supporters[:id].maximum.as('max_supporters_id')).group(supporters[:supporter_id])
query  = supporters.project(max_id)
                   .join(supporters[:project_id])
                     .on(supporters[:max_supporter_id].eq(supporters[:id]))
                   .where(supporters[:project_id].eq(project_id))
query.to_sql
# => "SELECT (SELECT MAX(\"supporters\".\"id\") AS max_supporters_id FROM \"supporters\"  GROUP BY \"supporters\".\"supporter_id\") FROM \"supporters\" INNER JOIN \"supporters\".\"project_id\" ON \"supporters\".\"max_supporter_id\" = \"supporters\".\"id\" WHERE \"supporters\".\"project_id\" = 1"

query.to_a # executes the query and returns records
```

For more informations about building the complex queries in rails, you could read there https://github.com/rails/arel 
I wish it helps.

Comment: Itsnikolay, thanks for taking the time for doing this! Appreciate it